# Angular ng-click show popup relative to clicked element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to show a hidden element positioned relative to the link that was clicked to trigger it.

I know how to use ng-click and ng-show, but I can't seem to figure out how to position the "shown" element in relation to the "clicked" element.

Thoughts?

-Yellowradio

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways you could do this depending on the complexity of the thing you are trying to popup. You could easily create a directive that handles everything including hooking up the click event on your element, generating the html for the popup content and then displaying it in the correct position. The code for the entire example is a little long to post here but here is the directive:

```
angular.module("myModule", []).directive("popupLauncher", function($rootScope, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var popup = "<div class='popup'>" + attrs['popupLauncher'] + "</div>";
        element.click(function() {
            var popups = $(".popup");
            if (popups.length > 0) {
                 //if it exists remove it (this allows for only one popup at a time on the screen)  
                popups.remove();
            } else {
                //if it doesn't add it
                var compiledElement = $compile(popup)($rootScope.$new());
                $('body').append(compiledElement);
                //figure out the coordinates of where you want the popup
                var topOfTrigger = element.offset().top;
                var leftOfTrigger = element.offset().left;
                var rightOfTrigger = leftOfTrigger + parseInt(element.css("width")); //don't use width() as it doesn't include margins and padding
                var bottomOfTrigger = topOfTrigger + parseInt(element.css("height"))
                //this will position it at the bottom right of the clicked element but
                //using the variables above you can change that
                $(compiledElement).css("top", bottomOfTrigger)
                    .css("left", rightOfTrigger);

                //you may want to hook up a resize listener on the body to reposition if the 
                //popup is visible when the page resizes
                //also, you may want  a click event on the body to close it when you click off
                //right now this requires that you click on the trigger again

            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

And here is the important CSS:

```
.popup {

    position:absolute;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    padding:10px;
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
<button popup-launcher="this is the popup content">popup</button>
```

see this fiddle for a working directive and sample CSS for styling the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/mcgraphix/s8506hm8/

This utilized JQuery but you could easily do the DOM manipulation/positioning yourself.

Comment: Just a note: You only need to $compile service if the content of your popup is itself going to have angular code in it. For example a directive or ng-click